# HTML - Displaying an img only in :hover state of a navbar

Tags: html, css, hover, navbar

I would like to know if it's possible to display an img on a navbar only when :hover is active in html/css language only.

i'm trying to show this light under my nav bar when i :hover
[navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS2L4.png)

this is my html code :[codeHtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yiopi.png)

and this is my css : [css for the img positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viRtV.png)

1 question can i do this without JS? (by just playing with opacity). Beceasue i tryed 
ul li a img{opacity: 0;}

ul li a img:hover{opacity:1;}
and it didnt work.

2 can i use the same img again for other navbar element with différent value in the css to change the position,maybe using différent class? and just change teh size and the x value?if yes with absolute or relative?

thanx you for your anwser everyone , have a good day

Comment: You should put the :hover on the li element or the anchor element, not the image. That should work. for example li:hover img {opacity: 1}

Comment: Add real code to your question. Not images of code. See [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

only seeing all the code I could give a straight answer. However, trying this code:

```
    <ul>
    <li><a href="dsad">Home<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/63/IMG_%28business%29.svg/1200px-IMG_%28business%29.svg.png"></a></li>
    <li>teste</li>
    <li>outro</li>
    <li>Ultimo</li>
</ul>
<style>
    ul li a img:hover{opacity: 1;}
    ul li a img{opacity: 0;}
</style>
```

it works...

you want to put the image in an absolute position, considering the position of his parent (li) right? If so, I do not set the (li) with position:relative and the img with absolute? Like this, the absolute position of img would be through his parent (li) not from the whole document.

In the CSS that you published, you have opacity:0.9. So problably is this the cause. Try to put opacity:0; and in the in other line put - ul li:hover img{opacity:1 !important}

About question 2, off course. But maybe consider setting a class name for each navbar

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. Just hide the image on your stylesheet, then on **:hover** of the menu item (li). Display the image again!

```
ul li a img {
  display:none;
}

ul li:hover a img {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done just by playing with opacity

```
ul li a img {opacity:0;}
```

and add hover on list item

```
ul li:hover a img {opacity:1;}
```